# How to render html in addError method

Tags: apex

Could you please advise How to render html in addError method?

I am trying to display a html link in an error message that gets triggered up on insert.
The problem is that the entire html shows up along with the error message as a label.

Could you please advise How to render html in addError method?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000213462&language=en_US

Answer (score 3):

Try using the method: addError(String errorMsg, Boolean escape) and pass in the 2nd parameter as false to have the HTML rendered.

For example:

```
addError('<p>An Error has occurred</p>', false);
```

Comment: Hi, already tried

Comment: Hi, I've tried already the second parameter but still the HTML is not rendered. Also checked the entire implemetation of the addError method in the following link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError_2

Comment: Is the addError being called by an Apex class through the trigger or is it called directly from the trigger?
There seems to be a bug with it being called from a class [link](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008aa4), but from a trigger should be working as of winter 15.[link](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4PjAAK)

Comment: Is there anything else you can advise me to try becasue I still can't find a way to render the HTML?

Comment: It is called by an Apex class.